# Thymeleaf: shorthand for th:if="${myVar}" th:text="${myVar}"

Tags: thymeleaf

I frequently use

```
<myElem th:if="${myVar}" th:text="${myVar}">dummy</myElem>
```

Is there a more concise syntax with less repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is the short syntax you can use to render an html tag

Comment: what a pitty, it would be useful